# Transform m-ary tree to n-ary tree

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, tree

- Given a root of a tree. The tree may be of any depth and width,

  - i.e. each node may have any number of child nodes.
  - This method should transform a tree in such a way that each node (except probably one) would either have N or 0 children (and one node may have a number of children between 0 and N).
  - Algorithm may transform given tree in any way with only condition:
    if node A was an ascendant of node B in a source tree node B may not be an ascendant of a node A in a result tree (they may become siblings though).

```
interface CompactTreeBuilder<T> {
    /**
     *
     * E.g.
     *
     * source:        compact(A, 2)     compact(A, 1)             compact(A, 100)
     *
     * A               A                 A                         A
     *  |               |                 |_B                       |_B
     *  |_B             |_B                  |_C                    |
     *     |            |  |                    |_D                 |_C
     *     |            |  |_D                     |_E              |
     *     |            |  |                          |_F           |_D
     *     |_C          |  |_E                           |_G        |
     *     | |_D        |    |_H                            |_H     |_E
     *     |    |_F     |                                           |
     *     |            |_C                                         |_F
     *     |_E            |                                         |
     *       |_G          |_F                                       |_G
     *       |            |                                         |
     *       |_H          |_G                                       |_H
     *
     *
     *  in an example for compact(A,2) above node E is an exception node:
     *  it has 1 child while any other node has either 2 or 0 children
     */
    Node<T> compact(Node<T> root, int N);
    }
 
    class Node<T> {
    private final T data;
 
    private final List<Node<T>> children;
 
    public Node(T data, List<Node<T>> children) {
        this.data = data;
        this.children = children;
    }
 
    public T getData() {
        return data;
    }
 
    public List<Node<T>> getChildren() {
        return children;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A straightforward algorithm would be:

Traverse the input tree in breadth-first order. Add each visited node to the new tree, also in a breadth-first order, making sure to add children to a node that does not yet have N children, and only add a first child to the next leaf (in breadth-first order) when there is no more internal node that has fewer than N children.

This will ensure that:

- There will never be two nodes in the target tree that have fewer than N children.
- Nodes can only become parents of nodes that were added later. Since we traverse the input tree in breadth-first order this guarantees that nodes never become ancestors of any of their original ancestors